# kernel fails allocating crashkernel memory when using the KASLR kernel feautre

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader

i am using the 4.19.149 kernel on x86_64 platform running on centos6.2.
my compile kernel configuration contains the following options:

```
CONFIG_PHYSICAL_START=0x1000000
CONFIG_RELOCATABLE=y
CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
```

my kernel command line is:

```
?> cat /proc/cmdline
ro root=LABEL=/ rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=512M@0M nompath append="nmi_watchdog=2" printk.time=1 rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_DM dm_mod.use_blk_mq=y rcutree.kthread_prio=99 intel_pstate=enable intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=1 idle=halt console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8d
```

so to summarize thing:

1. i am requesting the kernel to allocate 512M for crashkernel at the low memory region.
   when looking in the kernel arch/x86/kernel/setup.c:
   i can see that for my configuration the memory the kernel tries allocating those 512M ar between 16M-
   896M:

   ````
   #define CRASH_ALIGN     (16 << 20)
   ...
   # define CRASH_ADDR_LOW_MAX (896UL << 20)
   ...
   static void __init reserve_crashkernel(void)
   ....
       if (crash_base <= 0) {
       /*
        * Set CRASH_ADDR_LOW_MAX upper bound for crash memory,
        * as old kexec-tools loads bzImage below that, unless
        * "crashkernel=size[KMG],high" is specified.
        */
       crash_base = memblock_find_in_range(CRASH_ALIGN,
                           high ? CRASH_ADDR_HIGH_MAX
                            : CRASH_ADDR_LOW_MAX,
                           crash_size, CRASH_ALIGN);
       if (!crash_base) {
           pr_info("crashkernel reservation failed - No suitable area found.\n");
           return;
       }```
   ````
2. since i am using the CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE option, on boot, before allocating the memory for the
   crashkernel, the boot loader extract my kernel into randomize physical address.
   code at arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr.c

the problem is that once i a while, the randomize kernel address causes failure in allocating memory for the crashkernel.
for example: on one of my reboots:

```
?> cat /proc/iomem
00000000-00000fff : Reserved
00001000-0009fbff : System RAM
0009fc00-0009ffff : Reserved
000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000f0000-000fffff : Reserved
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-bfff9fff : System RAM
  17000000-17c02fff : Kernel code
  17c03000-183523ff : Kernel data
  18883000-189fffff : Kernel bss
bfffa000-bfffffff : Reserved
c0000000-febfefff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  febf7000-febf707f : 0000:00:03.0
  febf8000-febf81ff : 0000:00:04.0
  febf9000-febf91ff : 0000:00:05.0
  febfa000-febfa1ff : 0000:00:06.0
  febfb000-febfb1ff : 0000:00:07.0
  febfc000-febfc1ff : 0000:00:08.0
  febfd000-febfd1ff : 0000:00:09.0
  febfe000-febfe03f : 0000:00:0a.0
fec00000-fec003ff : IOAPIC 0
fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC
fffbc000-ffffffff : Reserved
```

in this example the kernel gets 368M-380M, which leaves no room for my 512M crashkernel memory (not from top to bottom - 896M-380M is not enough and not from bottom up 16M-368M is not enough).
my questions are:

1. this seems like a bug in the KASLR feature - is this a known issue ?
2. is there a way to tell the KASLR to avoid randomizing the kernel address into the low memory region ? i can see that using the memmap command line parameter i can add memory regions which will achieve that, the problem is that those memmaps causes the allocation of the crashkernel to fail as well.
   thanks.